# eclipse, new maven project, spring boot - does not pull any libraries

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven

I am trying to create a basic Spring Boot app in Eclipse, but I am finding that Maven/Eclipse is NOT pulling the necessary basic Spring framework jars to let me continue developing.

I do this:

1) In Eclipse, choose New -> Maven Project
2) In the second dialog (skip archetypes) I enter all the info for my app, plus I enter info for parent app so that I end up with a pom that looks identical to the one from the spring boot reference guide, minus my own artifact/group being specific to my project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <!-- Inherit defaults from Spring Boot -->
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <!-- Add typical dependencies for a web application -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <!-- Package as an executable jar -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

At this point, I don't see any spring jars in the Maven Dependencies folder of the project like I would see in other projects (the folder in fact doesn't even exist) So i try:

3) Maven -> Run As -> Maven install
It says Build Successful. Still no libraries

4) right-click Project, Maven -> Update Project click OK
Still no libraries.

So at this point when I create my Application.java class and put in the annotation @SpringBootApplication, Eclipse flags it as an error that it "cannot be resolved to a type" and there is no auto fix to import it from the appropriate library, since my project has still not pulled any spring jars

What's going on? What did I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get around this my adding Variables in my project build path to copies of the spring jars in my local file system. I think it's a proxy issue that I cant reach the normal repository.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of copying local jars, you can add following in your pom.xml and in case you cannot reach any specific repository, you can switch to other by changing this configuration properties.

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>spring-releases</id>
    <name>Spring Releases</name>
    <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
  <pluginRepository>
    <id>spring-releases</id>
    <name>Spring Releases</name>
    <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
  </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```